# Clean URL's with .htaccess use or not slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

Yesterday I posted a question about the file .htaccess. Now is working, but I have another problem. For example:

When I try to go to "localhost/about", it doesn't work, it gives me an "Error 404":

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/user/enric/ was not found
>   on this server.

But when I go to "localhost/about/" it works. Why?

I want both URL's to work. Can anybody help me?

This is the code of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^channels/page/([0-9]+)/?$ channels/index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^channels/([_0-9a-z-]+)/?$ channels/index.php?o=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^channels/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ channels/index.php?o=$1&p=$2 [L]

# User profiles
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/$ /user/index.php?usr=$1 [L]

# Check to see if the URL points to a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Trailing slash check
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

# Add slash if missing & redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# Delete ".php" extension and adds "/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this slightly modified code in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^channels/page/([0-9]+)/?$ channels/index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^channels/([_0-9a-z-]+)/?$ channels/index.php?o=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^channels/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ channels/index.php?o=$1&p=$2 [L]

# User profiles
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/$ /user/index.php?usr=$1 [L]

# Check to see if the URL points to a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Trailing slash check
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
# Add slash if missing & redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# Delete ".php" extension and adds "/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I changed a part of the code because it doesn't work good with folders!

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]`